# mayaBatchRenderProcedure.mel line 653: Renderer returned an error while rendering 'defaultRenderLayer' - Maya CommandLine Linux

Tags: python, linux, maya

I am trying to render some image of a MAYA Ascii file on linux command line (in order to build a mov in ffmpeg) (it HAS to be on linux command line due to render farm setup)

I have the follwing env variable :

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then i have use the following cmd (build up in a python wrap of the scene context)

```
Render -r hw2  -x 960 -y 540 -s 101 -e 131 -of png -cam persp -rd /mnt/smf/03_FAB/ANIM/110/110_Sq0060/110_Sq0060Sh0390/images/REVIEW/tmp_SMF_110_Sq0060Sh0390_ANIM_build_v000_000 -im frame -fnc name.#.ext /mnt/smf/03_FAB/ANIM/110/110_Sq0060/110_Sq0060Sh0390/wip/MAYA/SMF_110_Sq0060Sh0390_ANIM_build_v000_000_test.ma
```

> HW2 -> hardware renderer
> -x -y -> size of img output
> -s -e -> begin and end frame
> -of -> extention
> -rd -> output directory
> -im -> sat the name of the file
> -fnc ->the name with incrementation of the frame numbre last arg is the maya file

When i send the job to deadline to render on our linux pool i cant get it working, i keep having the following error

```
2020-08-21 09:54:02:  0: STDOUT: Result: /mnt/smf/03_FAB/ANIM/110/110_Sq0040/110_Sq0040Sh0200/wip/MAYA/SMF_110_Sq0040Sh0200_ANIM_build_v000_005.ma
2020-08-21 09:54:02:  0: STDOUT: Warning: file: /usr/autodesk/maya2018/bin/../scripts/others/makeCameraRenderable.mel line 45: Found camera Cam_001:Cam_SHAPEShape.
2020-08-21 09:54:02:  0: STDOUT: ogsRender  -layer defaultRenderLayer  ;
2020-08-21 09:54:02:  0: STDOUT: Warning: file: /usr/autodesk/maya2018/bin/../scripts/others/mayaBatchRenderProcedure.mel line 653: Renderer returned an error while rendering 'defaultRenderLayer', please verify the output image.
2020-08-21 09:54:02:  0: STDOUT: Scene /mnt/smf/03_FAB/ANIM/110/110_Sq0040/110_Sq0040Sh0200/wip/MAYA/SMF_110_Sq0040Sh0200_ANIM_build_v000_005.ma completed.
2020-08-21 09:54:03:  0: STDOUT: // Maya exited with status 0
```

And i got nothing in my img output repository except folders(project, SynColor ...)  and a 1k mayalog

If someone got a clue what is wrong it would save me.

(note : i have no render layer on the scene only master layer, the cam is an imported ABC)(the scene is a shot with import bg and asset as refs)

Comment: are you able to render a default scene on your farm with the hardware renderer?  Are you sure all the farm machines actually have video cards

Comment: yes they are only GPU